# trying to loop through JsonNode but root jsonNode is duplicating the data

Tags: json, exception, jackson, concurrentmodification

I am trying to loop through Jsonnode but root jsonNode is duplicating the data.
Trying to figure out but not sure where i am missing the issue. Will try to explain the issue below.

I have to Jackson API.

Json block is:

{
                    "queries": [

```
                    {
                        "id": "keyword",
                        "values": [
                            "test"
                        ]
                    },{
                        "id": "include",
                        "values": [
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

My block of Java code is Iterator fieldNames = root.fieldNames(); 
            while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

```
            String fieldName = fieldNames.next(); 
            if (fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("queries")) { 
                nameNode =root.get(fieldName);
            }

            JsonNode nameNode = root.get("queries");



            for (JsonNode node : nameNode) {
                JsonNode elementId =  node.path("id").asText();

                    if (!elementId.isEmpty() && elementId.equalsIgnoreCase("include")) {
                        check = true;
                        include = node;
                    }
                }

    When debug comes to line    for (JsonNode node : nameNode) { , node value is "id": "keyword", "values": [ "test" ] and nameNode is the json shown above but when it comes to next line which is " node.path("id").asText();"
```

nameNode variable appends  "id": "keyword","values": [  "test"  ] 2 times.

Now the json is the original json with "id": "keyword","values": [  "test"  ]  appended 2 times and gives concurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 2):

change your variable node to objNode because node may be predifined value in jackson and you can also try to make for each variable to final

Comment: Thank you. Perfect solution.